# Godot 4, changing background color of a button

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have this function that creates a button. I'd like to change the background color of this button using a theme. This theme is already working for a button created manually. Here is my function :

```
var theme = load("res://themes/theme.tres")

func addButton():
    var newButton = Button.new()
    parentNode.add_child(newButton)
    newButton.theme = theme
```

However, when I execute the scene, my button still has its default color.

Can you tell me where is my mistake ?

Thank you

I tried to create a theme inside the function, but same result

Comment: Did you define stylebox for the states of the button?